# How to search for multiple substrings using instr()

Tags: sql, sqlite, substring, instr

I'm trying to get the position of a file extension in a given string using instr(). This could be a number of possible extensions, so I need search for multiple substrings (eg. "jpg", "mp4"...).

I've tried an OR statement, eg. instr(string,"jpg" OR "mp4"), with no luck.

```
SELECT instr(column, "jpg") FROM table;
```

Any ideas for solutions or alternatives would be welcome.

Comment: You tagged this sqlite and MySQL. Which one are you using?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sorry. Mistake on my end, using sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is what you need.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN instr(column, "jpg") > 0 
   THEN instr(column, "jpg") WHEN instr(column, "mp4") > 0 
   THEN instr(column, "mp4") ELSE 0 END  FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only one of `'jpg'`, `'mp4'` or any other extension may exist in the column, then you can use this:

```
SELECT instr(column, "jpg") + instr(column, "mp4") + .... FROM table;
```

For all the non existing extensions [`instr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) will return `0` so the result will be the starting position of the existing extension. 
If you store all the extensions in a table with name `extensions` with a single column `name`, you could cross join it to your table and get the results:

```
select
  t.column, sum(instr(t.column, e.name)) position
from table t cross join extensions e
group by t.column
```